# On the multiplicity of complete intersections

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a complete intersection. How can I prove that $\operatorname{mult}(R)\geq2^{\operatorname{codim}(R)}$, where $\operatorname{mult}(R)$ is the multiplicity and $\operatorname{codim}(R)=\operatorname{edim}(R)-\dim(R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows easily from §7, Proposition 7 in Bourbaki, *Algebre Commutative*, Chapitre VIII.

> PROPOSITION 7. - Supposons $A$ local. Soit $s$ un entier $\ge 1$ et, pour $1 \le i \le s$, soient $\delta_i$ un entier $>0$, $x_i$ un élément de $\mathfrak m_A^{\delta_i}$, et $\xi_i$ sa classe dans $\mathfrak m_A^{\delta_i}/\mathfrak m_A^{\delta_i+1}$. On suppose que $(x_1,\dots,x_s)$ est une suite sécante pour $A$. Notons ${\bf x}$ l'idéal de $A$ engendré par $(x_1, \dots, x_s)$. Alors on a $e(A/{\bf x}) \ge \delta_1\cdots\delta_se(A)$ avec égalité si $(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_s)$ est une suite complètement sécante pour $\operatorname{gr}(A)$.

Write $R=A/(x_1,\dots,x_s)$ with $A$ regular local, $x_1,\dots,x_s$ an $A$-sequence and $(x_1,\dots,x_s)\subset\mathfrak m_A^2$. Then $e(A)=1$ and $\delta_i\ge 2$ for all $i=1,\dots,s$, so $e(R)\ge 2^s$. (Obviously $s=\operatorname{codim}(R)$.)